# DHCP server with 2 NICd

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

I have `windows 2012 r2 x64` standard server.

That server has 2 NIC

1. `nic1` gather IP from LAN1
2. `nic2` - here i need run dhcp for LAN2 (black network)

This server will have firewall which will be use to set which ports and destinations in lan1 are allowed for users from LAN2

Is it this scenario possible configure on this type of server?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.... Windows can act as a router between networks, but (without additional software) can not selectively forward packets based of the criteria you are specifying. I would highly recommend a Linux or BSD based distribution for a task like this.